# Checking the validity of Green function using a operator using a certain limit

Tags: limits, fourier-analysis, periodic-functions, greens-function, greens-theorem

We have an operator of green function which can be written as $\Big(-i \frac{\partial}{\partial x} -a \Big)^2$ within the periodic boundary conditions, where   $x,y  \epsilon  ]-\pi, \pi].$

Using that operation I have derived a **GREEN** function which is 
$$G(x,y) = \frac{1}{2} e^{i(x-y)a}\Big(- |x-y|- i(x-y) \cot \pi a+\frac{\pi}{\sin^2 \pi a} \Big)$$

**Summary : I have to show the Green function like $G(-\pi , y) = G(\pi, y)$**

I understand how the derivation works and it's pretty long.  If anyone asks me how can I verify that Green function operator directly with that operator?** 
****I didn't understand what is the activity of** **active crease**? and why (x-y) should be zero for for Green function?

What I understand is that, I have to verify the periodicity of G (x,y) over the boundary conditions they have given. What terms in the Green function should verify the periodicity in **Fourier Space** for the operator I mentioned first?

Edit:

After I apply the operator on G a, I got    $(-i \partial_x - a)^2 G =  \delta$ and using this notation, I found the coefficients of $g_n$.

$G(x,y) = \sum_{n=-\infty} ^{\infty} g_n e^{n(x-y)}$

Since I know $g_n$ I understand how I got the green function expression $$G(x,y) = \frac{1}{2} e^{i(x-y)a}\Big(- |x-y|- i(x-y) \cot \pi a+\frac{\pi}{\sin^2 \pi a} \Big)$$

Comment: [what about $(-i \partial_x - a)^2 G =  \delta$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function#Definition_and_uses) (the Dirac delta) ?

Comment: Is there any way to say that the operator satisfies the boundary conditions  in few mathematics without doing a lot of calculations?